Creating an mesh and object from any closed path
For an architectural model, it is very important to draw a closed curve, create a 2D plane (or mesh) out of it and finally extrude it to a 3D object.
1. Step Creating the curve:
There are the concepts of creating a curve (Bezier, Circle, Nurbes) but you have to subdivide the nodes and drag them instead of adding new nodes one by one. I am also not sure how to make sure that the curve closes.
2. Step Creating the mesh:
This is an option I have not found yet. How do I turn it into
3. Step Creating the 3D object: Given a plane, I assume, one can extrude it. Is there any problem with this operation?

What would be the most simple workflow to use in this situation?


Selecting the start point and the end point of your curve and then pressing F will connect them.

Go to Object > Convert > Mesh to turn your bezier curve into a mesh




Go to edit mode and press F to fill in a face, or Ctrl + F for more options



Then you have a mesh object that you can extrude


